# How to properly print all the files name in a directory using PHP

Tags: php

The code below successfully print an array result of all the PHP files in a folder.

```
$search_data = glob('download/*.php');
print_r($search_data);
```

Below is the array result:

```
Array ( [0] => download/index.php
[1] => download/register.php )
```

Here is my question: how do I print all the files? I have tried adding the code below but it throws error:

> Uncaught TypeError: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

Code:

```
$json = json_decode($search_data, true);
foreach ($json as $data) {

//print or list all the files 
    echo  $files = $data;
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: @NancyMoore There is also https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.directoryiterator.php which is quite powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$search_data` isn't a json string to decode. It's already an array. You'd just loop through it normally. Then use `echo "$data<br>\n";`

Thus you'd have:

```
$search_data = glob('download/*.php');
foreach ($search_data as $data) {
    echo "$data<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, its as simple as...

```
<?php

$files = glob('download/*.php');

foreach($files as $file){
    echo $file . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can cycle the $search_data array into a foreach loop.
If you want to print only the name of each file, you can use pathinfo method to retrieve the base name.